# I cannot get pg-0.14.0 gem installed after Mountain Lion install

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew, osx-mountain-lion, gem

I have been trying for some time now to get my Rails development environment back up since I upgraded from Lion to Mountain Lion. The problem is specifically installing the pg-0.14.0 (postgresql) gem.

I have tried the instructions on this [post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/27985816073/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-riding-a-mountain-lion) but with no luck. I have tried uninstalling Postgres with Homebrew and then reinstalling it. Nothing is working. If I try to install this gem I recieve this error:

> Building native extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error
>   installing pg:    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb checking for pg_config... yes Using config values from
>   /usr/local/bin/pg_config checking for libpq-fe.h... yes checking for
>   libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
>   checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no checking for PQconnectdb() in
>   -llibpq... no checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.

Where can I find 'mkmf.log'? Can anyone give me a suggestion on how to install the pg gem again?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the Command Line Tools for Xcode installed? These would be required.

Try `brew doctor` it will diagnose common issues that would affect general compilation issues on Mac.